# Rich Snippet errors "This is not verified publisher markup", and "Missing required field 'updates'/'author'"

Tags: seo, microformats, google-rich-snippets

When I test [my website](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=allinworld99.blogspot.com) on Google SDTT it will show:

> This is not a verified publisher markup.
>   Error: Missing required field "updated".
>   Error: Missing required hCard "author".

How can I solve it? And is this affecting my SEO rating?

[image: Screenshot of errors as shown by Google’s SDTT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to integrate your personal Plus profile with website and vice versa.

Follow this:

- Create a link to your Google+ profile from your webpage, like this:

  ```
  <a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Google</a>
  ```
- Replace `[profile_url]` with the your Google+ profile URL, like this:

  ```
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/109412257237874861202? rel=author">Google</a>
  ```
- Your link must contain the `?rel=author` parameter. If it's missing, Google won't be able to associate your content with your Google+ profile.
- Add a reciprocal link back from your profile to the site(s) you just updated.
- Edit the Contributor To section.
- In the dialog that appears, click Add custom link, and then enter the website URL.
- If you want, click the drop-down list to specify who can see the link.
- Click Save.

More here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?expand=option2

---

UPDATE:

In a very latest update issued today only, Google has confirmed that they are completely removing authorship feature from Google search. Pls follow updates here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [hEntry](http://microformats.org/wiki/hentry) Microformat. This Microformat *requires* three classes:

- `entry-title`
- `updated`
- `author`

You are missing `updated` and `author`.

(See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67264/17633) to a question with a similar problem.)

These errors most likely won’t affect your ranking, Google might just consider not showing a Rich Snippet.